# Using ForEach inside a Picker

Tags: swiftui, foreach, uipickerview, swiftui-foreach

I'm having issues pulling data from an Array into a picker using SwiftUI. I can correctly make a list of the data I'm interested in, but can't seem to make the same logic work to pull the data into a picker. I've coded it a few different ways but the current way I have gives this error:

```
Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'Text' conform to 'TableRowContent'
```

The code is below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BumpSelector: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = ViewModel()
    @State var selectedStyle = 0
        
    init(){
        model.getData2()}
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List (model.list) { item in
                Text(item.style)}
           
            Picker("Style", selection: $selectedStyle, content: {
                ForEach(0..<model.list.count, content: { index in
                    Text(index.style)
                           })
                       })
            }
}
```

The model is here:

```
import Foundation

struct Bumps: Identifiable{
    var id: String
    var style: String
}
```

and the ViewModel is here:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list = [Bumps]()
    @Published var styleArray = [String]()
   
    func getData2() {
           
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("bumpStop").getDocuments { bumpSnapshot, error in

            //Check for errors first:
            if error == nil {

                //Below ensures bumpSnapshot isn't nil
                if let bumpSnapshot = bumpSnapshot {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        self.list = bumpSnapshot.documents.map{ bump in

                            return Bumps(id: bump.documentID,
                                         style: bump["style"] as? String ?? "")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                //Take care of the error
            }
        }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` in your `ForEach` is just an `Int`, there is no style associated with an `Int`. You could try this approach to make the `Picker` work with its `ForEach`:

```
struct BumpSelector: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = ViewModel()
    @State var selectedStyle = 0
    
    init(){
        model.getData2()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List (model.list) { item in
                Text(item.style)}
            
            Picker("Style", selection: $selectedStyle) {
                ForEach(model.list.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(model.list[index].style).tag(index)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

`Text(model.list[selectedStyle].style)` will give you the required `style` of the `selectedStyle`.
However, as always when using index, you need to ensure it is valid at the time of use.
That is, use `if selectedStyle < model.list.count { Text(model.list[selectedStyle].style) }`.

You could also use this alternative approach that does not use `index`:

```
 struct Bumps: Identifiable, Hashable {   // <-- here
     var id: String
     var style: String
 }

 struct BumpSelector: View {
     @ObservedObject var model = ViewModel()
     @State var selectedBumps = Bumps(id: "", style: "") // <-- here
     
     init(){
         model.getData2()
     }
     
     var body: some View {
         VStack{
             List (model.list) { item in
                 Text(item.style)
             }
             Picker("Style", selection: $selectedBumps) {
                 ForEach(model.list) { bumps in
                     Text(bumps.style).tag(bumps)  // <-- here
                 }
             }
         }
         .onAppear {
             if let first = model.list.first {
                 selectedBumps = first
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Then use `selectedBumps`, just like any `Bumps`, such as `selectedBumps.style`

Comment: So indices basically break the data down to be counted by the ForEach loop? Then the Text line just goes through and pulls each one? I am also not sure how to take the "selectedStyle" state integer and turn it into text of the actual style that exists in the database. How do I pull that specific part from the database again before I get into the body of the view? I tried             `Text(String(model.list[selectedStyle].style))` outside of the picker but that gave me an out of range error

Comment: Re your comment/question, yes. Updated my answer with more info and an alternative approach.
You could also use your original setup `ForEach(0..<model.list.count, content: { index in ...}`
 but `indices` in my opinion is more appropriate.

Comment: When I use your Edit 1 method it build fine but I don't get a picker. If I do:
`Picker("Style", selection: $selectedStyle, content: { ForEach(model.list.indices, id: \.self) { index in Text(model.list[index].style).tag(index)}}) `
I get a picker that works but I have no way to use the tag to actually tell me what style I chose. I only get the integer.

Comment: Why can I only show the style when I put the if loop to check if the index is valid? 
`if selectedStyle < model.list.count { Text(model.list[selectedStyle].style) }` works but `Text(model.list[selectedStyle].style) ` throws an error.

Comment: re: `Why can I only ...`, it is 
because your function `getData2())` is an asynchronous function.

It take sometimes before the results are available. But in the mean time 
your UI is refreshed, and at first there is no `Bumps` in your `@Published var list`. 
When you try to retrieve the `selectedStyle=0` element of the `list` with  `model.list[selectedStyle]` 
the app crashes. The `if selectedStyle < ...` will stop the app crashing.

A fraction of a second later, your results are ready and the UI is refreshed again, and now you have something in your `list` 
and all works.

Comment: Just for info, to understand my previous comment, you need to understand swift `Array`.
See for example: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html
 An array has elements, and the first element is at `model.list[0]`, **not** at `model.list[1]`.
 So if you try accessing the first element of an empty list the app will crash.